# htaccess permanent redirect of shared host subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have domain like:

someword.com.s123234.gridserver.com

I am trying to .htaccess redirect like

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^someword.com.s123234.gridserver.com/$

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.someword.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but the redirect is not working.

How can I permanently redirect this type of domain?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the point means something to htaccess (namely "all characters), you have to write . instead.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^someword\.com\.s123234\.gridserver\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.someword.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```